# Visualization of $n$-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, linear-algebra, visualization

I am learning quantum physics, and came across $n$-dimensional Hilbert spaces, is there any way one can visualize a $n$-dimensional space and the n components of the vectors existing in that space?

P.S. I am currently in 10th grade and don't know who to ask. It will be really amazing if someone could help.

Comment: The sad answer is that in general there is no way to visualize a $n$-dimensional complex space as easily as you can visualize 1-, 2- or 3-D space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to first get a broader understanding of what a vector space is. By far the most common example of a vector space is a set of little arrows that you add tip to tail and multiply by stretching.

If you look up the definition of a vector space, for example in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), you find that it is a set of objects that can be added together and multiplied by numbers. Certain rules must apply to make sure the way addition and multiplication work match the usual way. Arrows fit the definition, but so do many other things.

Some more extremely common vector spaces are the set of ordered pairs, triples, and other n-tuples. So visualizing the set of ordered 4-tuples is visualizing a 4D vector space.

There are other examples. The set of functions of the format $a_0 + a_1 x + a_x x^2$ is a set of objects that can be added together and multiplied by numbers. It is a 3D vector space. You can visualize it as graphs - a set of lines and lines and parabolas. A 4D or 5D space has some more complicated curves.

This is not what you usually think of when you imagine a vector space, but it is related to the kind of vector space used in quantum mechanics. Quantum mechanics is all about wave functions. The set of all wave functions is the vector space you need to visualize.

This is more complex than the previous function space for a number of reasons. First, the functions are defined in 3D space rather than in a 1D number line. Second, the value of the function at each point is a complex number instead of a real number. 3rd, there is a restriction on which functions are allowed in the space. The magnitude is calculated by $\int \psi^*\psi dx$. The magnitude must be 1.

So it is still a challenge to visualize. But at least it doesn't require visualizing arrows in N dimensional space.

Comment: makes sense! Now I understand it better thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest representation is to visualise the vectors as $ n \times 1$ column matrices. Dual space vectors are $ 1 \times n$ row matrices. The inner product is a matrix multiplication between row vectors and column vectors.

For example, the three orthogonal space axes correspond to three positions in a $3\times 1$ column matrix. In an $n$-dimensional matrix, the orthogonal axes are represented by column matrices with a $1$ in one row, and $0$ in every other row.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But my question was about something else. In n-dimensional space, there can be n vectors that can be placed orthogonally, so is there any way to visualize this. For eg in a 3-dimensional space, there are three axes î,  ĵ, k̂.

Comment: It is more accurate to visualise 3-space as being represented by $3 \times 1$ column matrices.

Comment: *For eg in a 3-dimensional space, there are three axes î, ĵ, k̂* You've answered you're own question, haven't you? How would you visualise a $4$-dimensional plane, for example? $u=a_0+a_1x+a_2y+a_3z$ In $\text{3D}$ space that's just not possible. You only have the mathematical description to work with.

Comment: Yes, I understand! The mathematical description sums up the whole system! Got it